# MDX, calculated member with olap cube

Tags: mdx, olap-cube, cubes

I have a question related to cubes with Microsoft Technologies, we have an SSAS Cube built on BIDS 2008 version, and the requirement is to group (sum) the measure quantity taking the previous twelve months and excluding some values in one dimension.

I have come up with a calculation inside the cube as follows:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[N-12]
 AS Sum
    (
      (
        Except
        (
          [Dim Sistema Corporativo].[Sistema Corporativo].[Id Sistema]
         ,{
            [Dim Sistema Corporativo].[Sistema Corporativo].[Id Sistema].&[3]
           ,[Dim Sistema Corporativo].[Sistema Corporativo].[Id Sistema].&[4]
          }
        )
       ,lastperiods(12,
          [Dim Tiempo].[Fecha].CURRENTMEMBER
        )
      )
     ,
       [Measures].[importe]

    )/*Lime*/,
VISIBLE = 1  ;
```

I get something like this:

```
Row        Importe       N-12
2011    12399121166 12399121166
01.2011 1040785565  1040785565
02.2011 1069453202  2110238768
03.2011 1359303502  3469542269
04.2011 1068266294  4537808563
05.2011 1163538168  5701346731
06.2011 1146393010  6847739741
07.2011 936369144.8 7784108886
08.2011 1000363518  8784472404
09.2011 859885351.7 9644357755
10.2011 779035206.2 10423392962
11.2011 933409920.9 11356802882
12.2011 1042318283  12399121166
2012    25162093544 22225879797
01.2012 -40878580.57    11317457020
02.2012 678706164.3 10926709982
03.2012 16323643149 10555714716
04.2012 947692878   10435141301
05.2012 1057496411  10329099544
06.2012 1103249990  10285956525
07.2012 976810086.3 10326397466
08.2012 1046738046  10372771994
09.2012 1027644991  10540531634
10.2012 1108157924  10869654352
11.2012 932832484   10869076915
12.2012             9826758631
2013                22225879797
2014                22225879797
2015                22225879797
2016                22225879797
2017                22225879797
2018                22225879797
2019                22225879797
2020                22225879797
2021                22225879797
2022                22225879797
2023                9826758631
```

As you can see it is doing the right thing altough the user asked me to make some tweaks:

First one is that the cube does not show anything if theres no data (identified as "importe" measure group) and as you can see it shows blank spaces for the next years (until 2023) when when there's no data for the default measure group.

Second one is that the user **only wants to see data if and only if the current member has 12 previous months** so for example, right now is showing info for the year 2011 but as the user said it should only display data for the year 2012 because all those months have previos 12 months and 2011 does not have 2010 data so for this I should have a null value.

is it possible to do this...???

or maybe you can suggest any other option like affecting the fact table directly and so on.

Thank you in advise guys.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the current member has 12 previous month you can use an expression like this one:

```
IIf(Count(
          NonEmpty(lastperiods(12, [Dim Tiempo].[Fecha].CURRENTMEMBER), 
                   [Measures].[importe])
          ) = 12,
    ...,
    ...)
```

Comment: thanks a lot amigo, I modified the mdx calculation and get it done, thanks master for your help.